# Is $\mathbb{Z}[ \alpha ]$ Noetherian for $\alpha \in \mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, solution-verification

If $\alpha$ is algebraic, this follows from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}$ Noetherian, and:

$$ \mathbb{Z}[X]/(f) \cong \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] $$

where $f$ is the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$. (Note: $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ Noetherian by Hilbert's basis theorem.) If $\alpha$ is transcendental, it doesn't have a minimal polynomial. But then:

$$\phi:\mathbb{Z} [\alpha] \to \mathbb{Z} [X], \hspace{1cm} k_0+k_1\alpha+\cdots+k_n\alpha^n \mapsto k_0+k_1X+\cdots+k_nX^n$$

is a ring isomorphism. It can be verified that this has the properties of a homomorphism.

Further, this is well-defined; suppose $r=s$, but $\phi (r) \neq \phi(s)$. Then, $\phi(r-s) = 0$ since $\phi$ preserves addition. But then, there exists a polynomial $f = \phi(r-s)$ s.t. $f(\alpha)=0$ which is a contradiction.

Hence, $\mathbb{Z} [\alpha] \cong \mathbb{Z}[X]$ is Noetherian.

Is this argument correct? I was inclined to believe the statement was false because it was not proven in lectures, and I spent a lot of time trying to disprove it at first. It would be great if anyone could lend some more intuition on this topic also.

Comment: You need to argue that $\Bbb Z[X]$ is Noetherian - by Hilbert's basis theorem.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes, I didn't write that but I am using that. I will make an edit.

Comment: Yes your argument is correct, and this question could be helpful  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1220280/let-alpha-in-r-prove-that-mathbb-q-alpha-cong-mathbb-qx-iff-alpha

Comment: @Laassilasouhayl Great, thank you. Is there any larger significance to this apparent correspondence between transcendental numbers and polynomials?

Comment: You can also do it without splitting into cases. There is a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[x]\to\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$, and so $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a quotient of a Noetherian ring, thus Noetherian. More generally, if $A$ is a Noetherian ring and $B$ is a finitely generated algebra over $A$ then $B$ is Noetherian. (because again, $B$ is a quotient of $A[x_1,...,x_n]$ for some $n$)

Comment: @Mark Right, of course. That was actually an earlier part of the question :/